# WebStorm 11 fresh install not starting in Mac OSX

Tags: java, jvm, osx-yosemite, webstorm, osx-elcapitan

This happened to me in fresh installs both in **El Capitan** and **Yosemite**. WebStorm 11.0.3.

When trying to start WebStorm from whatever source (Finder, Spotlight etc.) it seems like it does nothing at all. No visible errors, nothing at all.

So I tried to start it again with OSX's **Console** utility opened and I caught these:

```
08/02/16 12:57:29,912 webstorm[99959]: Cannot load JVM bundle: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "The bundle “OpenJDK 8” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources." (dlopen_preflight(/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib: file too short) UserInfo=0x610000069a40 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle is damaged or missing necessary resources., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib, NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib: file too short, NSBundlePath=/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/jre/jdk, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “OpenJDK 8” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.}
```

When applying the first step stated in the solution down below, I saw these:

```
08/02/16 13:01:01,146 webstorm[99970]: Value of WEBSTORM_JDK: (null)
08/02/16 13:01:01,149 webstorm[99970]: fullFileName is: /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/bin/webstorm.vmoptions
08/02/16 13:01:01,149 webstorm[99970]: fullFileName exists: /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/bin/webstorm.vmoptions
08/02/16 13:01:01,149 webstorm[99970]: Value of WEBSTORM_VM_OPTIONS is (null)
08/02/16 13:01:01,149 webstorm[99970]: Processing VMOptions file at /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/bin/webstorm.vmoptions
08/02/16 13:01:01,149 webstorm[99970]: Done
08/02/16 13:01:01,150 webstorm[99970]: JNI_CreateJavaVM (/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/jre/jdk) failed: 4294967295
```

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544909-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks -- Java 1.6 is required for launching WebStorm v11/PhpStorm v10. The next version though (WebStorm v12/PhpStorm v11 -- EAP is already running for a month) will use Java v8 directly so you will need to revert your modifications when you will start using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching in GitHub, Jetbrain's forums and so on I saw other people with JVM issues but didn't solve entirely my problem.

For the `libjli.dylib` issue, I searched for that file in Webstorm.app's contents and saw that it exists in two places, but one of the files (the one that says the file is too short) looks like it's just a redirection to the other file. So I just copied the bigger `libjli.dylib` and replaced the one being complained about.

To my knowledge, now there's no redirection and the Console is clear from that error. But Webstorm still wasn't starting, now showing the second error, `JNI_CreateJavaVM failed`.

Turns out something's not quite right in Webstorm and the new versions of Java. I happen to be using the Java 1.8.

What I saw recommended and also worked for me was installing also the Java 1.6 using **Brew** and telling Webstorm.app to use that version instead. Bear in mind that doing it this way, **your system will keep using the updated Java version**

So first installing Java 1.6 in the terminal:

```
~ brew tap caskroom/versions
[...]
~ brew cask install java6
[...]
  java6 staged at '/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/java6/1.6.0_65' (64M)
```

And now telling Webstorm to use **1.6**:

1. Open up `Info.plist` file from Webstorm.app contents folder.
2. Change the line below `<key>JVMVersion</key>` from `<string>1.6+,1.7+</string>` to `<string>1.6</string>`
3. Save and close

And now it's working!

If Webstorm.app tries to use a Java version you don't have (or can't be found), you'll see something like this:

[image]

Again, for me, this was fixed using Brew.

Comment: I would not recommend using JDK 6.  Even JDK 7 has passed the end of its support life.  JDK 8 is what you should be using.

Comment: I'm aware they are not very bold. Did you read the part where Webstorm 11 doesn't start with 1.8 though?

Comment: No, didn't scroll over that far.  I think your solution lies in figuring out why JDK 8 won't work.  Are you a Java developer?  Does this mean you can't compile or run with JDK 8?

Comment: I'm not. And I already found a KISS solution. In case you're not aware, only Webstorm will be using the 1.6. Everything else will be using 1.8+ so I don't see the issue (also, please read the whole thing before giving out recommendations)

Comment: You don't need to be rude mate, we're here to help each other. FYI, from the Jetbrains website: "Please install Apple JDK 1.6. Current JDK 1.7 and 1.8 versions have several critical issues. We can't default to the new JDK version until these issues are resolved." and: "Apple still updates this JDK, 1.6.0_65 version was released not too long ago. As this JDK provides the best experience with our products, it will be used by default."