# NoClassDefFoundError and NullPointerException when opening a project with PhpStorm on OS X Sierra

Tags: java, php, macos, phpstorm, java-9

Recently installed PhpStorm 2017.2.4 on my Mac Pro (Sierra 10.12.6), Java version is (9+181).

Whenever I try to open a project, PhpStorm hangs.
I took a look at the log file situated in `/Library/Logs/PhpStorm2017.2`.
There are several NoClassDefFoundError happening, with a slice of NullPointerException.
Here are a few excerpts:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/apple/eawt/AppEvent$AboutEvent
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/apple/eawt/OpenURIHandler
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxKt
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowManagerImpl.b(ToolWindowManagerImpl.java:1800)
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DaemonListeners$MyProfileChangeListener.a(DaemonListeners.java:519)
```

- I tried to change the target java version in the `info.plist` configuration file inside the PhpStorm package.
- I also followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270187/webstorm-11-fresh-install-not-starting-in-mac-osx) in order to be able to start the application.
- Just to check I also installed Webstorm, which worked perfectly out of the box.

After doing some research, it looks like no one else is having this problem. I really need some inspiration, some crazy idea to try.

PS: I uploaded the log file [here](https://ufile.io/6fh5g) if anyone feels like wading through it.

Comment: *"Java version is (9+181)"* AFAIK PhpStorm should use own bundled JDK .. which should be v8. This is what I see on my Windows PC in `Help | About` (yes, different OS but still): `JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b11 amd64` `JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o`. So .. try using bundled JDK/Java version.

Comment: @LazyOne: that's what I thought too. But PhpStorm wasn't even able to start until I installed a JDK. It couldn't find the libjava.dylib. Actually that gives me an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better solution, you can install PhpStorm with `homebrew`

```
homebrew cask install phpstorm
```

Worked like a charm.

I'm leaving the old answer, just in case someone needs this kind of information.

> Ooookay, I got it working. But that was not pretty.
>
> So for some reason PhpStorm is not able to use its own bundled JDK. It's trying to use the system's default JDK, which is Java 9 for me.
>
> Therefore i did something a bit extreme, I replaced the `lib` folder in the system's JDK by a symbolic link pointing to the jre `lib` folder inside the `Phpstorm.app` package
>
> ```
> sudo ln -s /Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home/lib
> ```
>
> Needless to say that you should *not* use this method if you have other applications using the system's JDK.
>
> Thanks to LazyOne, whose comment gave me the 'aha!' moment.
>
> PS: if anyone needs this information, I also had to give executing permissions to `fsnotifier` in order to be able to browse files within the IDE
>
> ```
> chmod 744 /Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/bin/fsnotifier
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I had this with Intelli-J when upgrading the jdk it runs on to 11.

I changed the jdk it runs on back down to 8 by following the instructions here:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

Might also need this link too for the config files locations

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519